# Rearranging cells between sections

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I know how to swap cells if they are underneath one section because internet is full of that but I'm struggling with the same having two sections. I cannot move every cell because obviously index is out of range. I thought it would be unnecessary to post the whole code so I'll paste only the important bits

I have declared:

```
let sections: [String] = ["Box", "Inventory"]
    var s1Data: [UIImage] = [] //
    var s2Data: [UIImage] = [] //these are filled by other function

let sectionsImages: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blackBox"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blackBag")]

var sectionData: [[UIImage]] = []
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
tableView.isEditing = true


tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

sectionData = [s1Data, s2Data]
```

Then quite a number of tableView functions, but the one I cannot go through and the one I'm talking about:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        let item = sectionData[sourceIndexPath.row]
        sectionData.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        sectionData.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

And so, swapping goes fine until I try to swap the last image cell because of mentioned 'out of bounds' failure. I know I should declare item as something like:

```
let item = sectionData[sourceIndexPath.section][sourceIndexPath.row]
```

but what about "remove" and "insert"?
I would be thankful for your help

EDIT:

I did it, although I don't know if it is one of the simpler way. Anyway:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if sourceIndexPath.section == 0 && destinationIndexPath.section == 0
    {
        let item = sectionData[0][sourceIndexPath.row]
        sectionData[0].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        sectionData[0].insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    else if sourceIndexPath.section == 0 && destinationIndexPath.section == 1
    {
        let item = sectionData[0][sourceIndexPath.row]
        sectionData[0].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        sectionData[1].insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    else if sourceIndexPath.section == 1 && destinationIndexPath.section == 0
    {
        let item = sectionData[1][sourceIndexPath.row]
        sectionData[1].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        sectionData[0].insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    else if sourceIndexPath.section == 1 && destinationIndexPath.section == 1
    {
        let item = sectionData[1][sourceIndexPath.row]
        sectionData[1].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        sectionData[1].insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    else
    {
        print("ERROR - SWAP MALFUNCTION")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, the insert uses the destinationIndexPath.section:

```
groupItems[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
groupItems[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
```